# Jenkins - What is consoleFull?

Tags: build, jenkins

I have a problem for building using Jenkins.
When I uploaded a patch code, build FAILED with this error.

```
jenkins     3:51 PM
Patch Set 1: 
[FAILED] Ant Build -> http://jenkins.lge.com:8086/jenkins/job/AgentApp/1329/consoleFull
```

What the **consoleFull** means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a link - where you can find full console output (logs). Just open http://jenkins.lge.com:8086/jenkins/job/AgentApp/1329/consoleFull -> and check the errors.

Comment: Got it. It just means full console message. I thought that some problem about conole made build error.